# Multitenancy with KeyCloak

Tags: keycloak

We have a system that utilizes different tenants, where users can be part of one or multiple tenants. You can imagine it as one application, where users can switch between the tenants and see assets related to the selected tenantId.
Our exernal KeyCloak adviser proposes to use one realm und reflect different tenants as clients in KeyCloak.

I´ve read on different sources, that it is not adviced to use multi tenancy with one realm, though i am not 100% sure if it applies for our usecase.

Additionaly we will need to have different groups on the same user, depending on the tenantId.
For example a user could have Group A and B on tenant 1 but only Group B on tenant 2. This doesnt seem to be possible out of box with KeyCloak.

Which general approach would you suggest?